# ng-mouseover & ng-mouseleave firing at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend

I'm trying to: **show/hide** an `<img>` tag. When **mouse is over**, it should **hide** the element and when **mouse leave** it should **show** it the tag back.

What i've tried:

```
<img ng-mouseover="active = true" ng-mouseleave="active = false"
     ng-init="active = true" ng-show="active">`
```

The problem: When the **mouse is over** ng-mouseleave is fired at the same time, making the element blink in a loop.

I tried to fix it thru directives but I got the same result.

Comment: did you try replacing `ng-mouseover` with `ng-mouseenter`?

Comment: The code doesn't match the description. The description says mouseover should hide, but the code is doing the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (based on your condition, not exactly as per your code which shows the opposite), when you implement it this way, the `mouseleave` automatically gets triggered after hiding the element on `mouseover`. This is because when the element becomes hidden based on the `ng-show` expression it also somehow simulate the mouse leaving the element. And due to this, it toggles the `ng-show` condition and makes it visible again and then the subsequent mouse events makes it loop indefinitely.

You should try using the `opacity` css property instead of using `ng-show` to achieve this. Also, your code seem to suggest just the opposite of what you intended to achieve.

Just tried this and it seems to work the way you intended.

```
<img ng-style="{'opacity': active ? 1 : 0}"  ng-mouseover="active = false" ng-mouseleave="active = true" ng-init="active=true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the element `<img>` element inside an `<a>` tag so `<a>` captures the mouse events and manipulate the active variable like so:

```
<a ng-mouseenter="active = false" ng-mouseleave="active = true"  href="#" >
    <img  ng-init="active = true" ng-show="active" src="/path.jpg" alt=""> 
</a>
```